# What does it mean for a tangent bundle to be parallel?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, vector-bundles

I am looking at page 8 of the paper [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211021v1.pdf), just below definition 2.13. I have never come across a phrase such as '$T\mathfrak{C}\subset{TM}$ is parallel' - what does it mean for a tangent bundle to be parallel? If someone could also please explain the concept of 'trivialising' a vector bundle (a couple of lines below, regarding the pullback bundle $c^*E\rightarrow(a,b)$), it would be much appreciated. I don't think these questions require any knowledge of the paper, except perhaps definition 2.12 for the concept of 'trivialising'. Thanks!

Comment: By the bundle being parallel it is meant in terms of the connection and parallel transport, in that case it is parallel since you are taking the tangent bundle to a geodesic.  As far as I understand trivializing just means taking a global section $[e]$ of the line bundle so to have a canonical trivialization defined above the whole geodesic.

Comment: @Spotty but $[\mathbf{e}]$ is a section of $c^*{TM}$, not the line bundle $E\rightarrow\mathfrak{C}$?